# slide animation on removing from basket

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux, css-animations

I am creating a application which is removing element on clicking 'remove from basket' button. Now I want to do it with animation. I have tried various ways but nothing got success. Can someone please help in adding sliding animation to it.

Below is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import "./CheckoutProduct.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";

export default function CheckoutProduct({
  id,
  image,
  title,
  price,
  rating,
  hideButton
}) {
  const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  const removeFromBasket = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "REMOVE_FROM_BASKET",
      id: id
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="checkoutProduct">
      <img className="CheckoutProduct__image" src={image} />
      <div className="CheckoutProduct__info">
        <p className="CheckoutProduct__title">{title}</p>
        <p className="CheckoutProduct__price">
          <small>$</small>
          <strong>{price}</strong>
        </p>
        <div className="CheckoutProduct__rating">
          {Array(rating)
            .fill()
            .map((_, i) => (
              <p></p>
            ))}
        </div>
        {!hideButton && (
          <button onClick={removeFromBasket}>Remove from basket</button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Remove from basket functionality is working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Framer-Motion Animation Library
first install `npm install framer-motion`

```js
import React from "react";
import "./CheckoutProduct.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";

import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { AnimateSharedLayout } from "framer-motion";

export default function CheckoutProduct({
  id,
  image,
  title,
  price,
  rating,
  hideButton
}) {
  const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  const removeFromBasket = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "REMOVE_FROM_BASKET",
      id: id
    });
  };

  return (
    <AnimateSharedLayout>
      <motion.div layout className="checkoutProduct">
        <img className="CheckoutProduct__image" src={image} />
        <motion.div layout className="CheckoutProduct__info">
          <p className="CheckoutProduct__title">{title}</p>
          <p className="CheckoutProduct__price">
            <small>$</small>
            <strong>{price}</strong>
          </p>
          <div className="CheckoutProduct__rating">
            {Array(rating)
              .fill()
              .map((_, i) => (
                <p></p>
              ))}
          </div>
          {!hideButton && (
            <motion.button onClick={removeFromBasket}>Remove from basket</button>
          )}
        </motion.div>
      </motion.div>
    </AnimateSharedLayout>
  );
}
```

Please share your code, in case it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use animate.css clean and simple [link](https://animate.style/) and the usage is really simple to use.